# For loop with chunk array exercise

Tags: for-loop

I wrote this code, could someone please explain how the i increments on each iteration as it seems to work:

```
function chunk(array, size) {
  let chunked = [];

  for (i = 0; i < array.length;) {
    chunked.push(array.splice(i, size));
  }

  return chunked;
}

let a = chunk([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 2);
console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "array.splice" removes "size" elements from the array. 
size is the parameter from you chunk function.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp

That means after each iteration the array.length is "size" shorter.
The loop ends when the array contains 0 elements.

In your example the chunk function removes 2 elements from the array on each iteration step.